# How to get an empty line merging texts?

Tags: text-processing

Is there a way to have the command

`cat *tab > newfile.tab`

insert an Blank Line between every file it merges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leverage a `for` construct:

```
GLOBIGNORE=newfile.tab
for f in *tab; do cat "$f"; echo; done >newfile.tab
```

Expanded:

```
GLOBIGNORE=newfile.tab
for f in *tab; do 
    cat "$f"; echo
done >newfile.tab
```

- `GLOBIGNORE=newfile.tab` is for excluding `newfile.tab` from shell globbing as that is our output file
- `for f in *tab` iterates over the files ending in `tab`
- `cat "$f"` outputs file content
- `echo` adds a newline
- The file descriptor from `>newfile.tab` redirection is kept open for the duration of `for` i.e. the file `newfile.tab` is opened-closed once

---

Also, you can use `printf` to do formatting once:

```
for f in file.txt*; do printf '%s\n\n' "$(<"$f")"; done
```

Expanded:

```
for f in file.txt*; do 
    printf '%s\n\n' "$(<"$f")"
done
```

Comment: Wow, much more complicated than i though. REALLY thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind an extra blank line after the last file, you could use `sed` e.g.

```
sed -s '$G' *.tab > newfile.tab
```

(this uses a GNU sed extension `-s` that treats input files separately; hence `$G` double spaces the last line of each file).

If you do mind the extra line, you could pipe it through another `sed`:

```
sed -s '$G' *.tab | sed '$d' > newfile.tab
```

---

Alternatively, with `awk`

```
awk 'FNR == 1 && NR != 1 {print ""} 1' *.tab > newfile.tab
```